# Using Zabbix monitor a VNF running on a private IP in openstack

Tags: openstack, zabbix

I have deployed some VNF's on [openstack](http://openstack.org/) using [openbaton](http://openbaton.github.io/) on a private network. I have enclosed a screenshot of openstack's network topology.

[image: screenshot of openstack network topology]

Now I want to monitor these VNFs using [zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/). To do so after ssh into a VNF with IP 10.0.0.3, I installed zabbix-agent on it and changed `ServerActive=<zabbix-server-IP-address>` in it's config file to allow for auto-registration of zabbix-agent. Correspondingly, I also added an action of `Add Host` & `Link to templates` on zabbix-server.

But after doing this, in the list of hosts in the zabbix-server, I am getting an entry as `<openstack-IP-address>:10050`, with an error message as

`Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to [[<openstack-IP-address>]:10050]: [111] Connection refused`

I think this is because the zabbix-agent is listening on port 10050 inside a VNF(which is on a private network). There is no zabbix-agent listening on port 10050 on `<openstack-IP-address>`.

What should I do so that zabbix-server can recognize the zabbix-agent running inside the VNF?

Comment: Very similar to https://serverfault.com/questions/885459/why-my-host-shows-up-as-unreachable-on-the-zabbix-server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially zabbix-server was installed on an external server.
That's why it was not able to access(ping / telnet) the VNF on the private network.
To solve this problem I installed zabbix-server on a VNF itself on the same private network. By doing this zabbix-server was able to monitor the zabbix-agents installed on other VNFs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use active items - that is, the mode where the agent connects to the server. You already use active agent auto-registration.

To do so, full-clone the default template and change all of these entities to active:

- items
- LLD rules
- LLD item prototypes

Then modify your action to link the cloned template instead, and "unlink & clear" the previously linked template.

Comment: Also https://serverfault.com/questions/885459/why-my-host-shows-up-as-unreachable-on-the-zabbix-server is very similar.